# Is it an issue to use "setAdapter()" more than once in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually I am fetching data from server and showing that on my `recyclerview` .But it was showing nothing . Even after a lot of question's reference my problem couldn't be solved but then I tried to use `setAdapter()` method after fetching data and now my problem is solved . But what I'm asking is **Is it unusual to use setAdapter more than once?** . In my first attempt I was setting adapter first then trying to use `adp.notifyDataSetChanged()` after fetching data from server. but now I'm setting adapter again after getting data.

Code:

```
private List<TImelineDataList> timelineDatalist;
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View v, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    timelineDataList= new ArrayList<>();
    adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(ctx,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
 void addTimelineData(String email,String time,String img_link,String caption){
    timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(email,time,img_link,caption));
    adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
  private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener(){

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)args[0];

               for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                   try {
                       JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       demo_email=ob.getString("_pid");

                       demo_time=ob.getString("time");

                       demo_link=ob.getString("img_link");

                       demo_caption=ob.getString("caption");


                       addTimelineData(demo_email,demo_time,demo_link,demo_caption);

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }




        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out the problem . The problem was there in constructing adapter twice . Now I've removed the next adapter construction and the `setAdapter()` as well and it's working without any errors.

**Previous Code**:

```
private List<TImelineDataList> timelineDatalist;
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View v, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    timelineDataList= new ArrayList<>();
    **adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);**//Here
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(ctx,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
 void addTimelineData(String email,String time,String img_link,String caption){
    timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(email,time,img_link,caption));
    **adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);**//Here
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
  private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener(){

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)args[0];

               for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                   try {
                       JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       demo_email=ob.getString("_pid");

                       demo_time=ob.getString("time");

                       demo_link=ob.getString("img_link");

                       demo_caption=ob.getString("caption");


                       addTimelineData(demo_email,demo_time,demo_link,demo_caption);

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }




        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

**New Code**:

```
private List<TImelineDataList> timelineDatalist= new ArrayList<>();;
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View v, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(ctx,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
 void addTimelineData(String email,String time,String img_link,String caption){
    timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(email,time,img_link,caption));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged():
}
  private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener(){

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)args[0];

               for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                   try {
                       JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       demo_email=ob.getString("_pid");

                       demo_time=ob.getString("time");

                       demo_link=ob.getString("img_link");

                       demo_caption=ob.getString("caption");


                       addTimelineData(demo_email,demo_time,demo_link,demo_caption);

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }




        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to get rid of setting the adapter  in `addTimelineData ()` `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead. See my answer for details.

Comment: Actually that's my writing mistake I forgot add the **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** to my answer

Comment: You should not call `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` after it

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method to update RecyclerView adapter after adding data into arraylist which is attached to adapter.

You can also call method `notifyItemInserted(index)` which can show item added with animation effect.

Comment: Thanks sir for your time but I've already tried them and those were not helpful

Comment: sir only this much task I'm doing apart from this I'm just caching data of recyclerview and I added that code now

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter or other methods from that family.
The problem with setting adapter will be that your scroll position will be lost.

It looks like the problem is in your `CustomRecyclerViewAdapter`. Good practice is to move `timelineDatalist` into the `CustomRecyclerViewAdapter` and have something like:

```
void addTimelineData(String email,String time,String img_link,String caption){
    adapter.addToTimelineDataList(new TimelineData(email,time,img_link,caption));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Please post your `CustomRecyclerViewAdapter` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think its usual to use setAdapter multiple times as it won't create any issues in functionality. But if you want to use

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

then try not to reinitialize your data while receiving the data if you perform

```
yourData = newData
```

then this will reinitialize your old data and notifyDataSetChanged() will not work on that

if its string then try concatenating in the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

make some change in method like below code ..

```
        void addTimelineData (String email, String time, String img_link, String caption){
        timelineDataList.clear()
        timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(email, time, img_link, caption));
        setAdapter();
    }
```

and make one setAdapter method like..

```
  public void setAdapter(){
    if (adpter==null){
        if(!timelineDataList.isEmpty()){
            adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);

        }
    }
    else{
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and remove the code onCreate() define recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);